# Event dispatcher in silex

Tags: events, dispatcher, silex

I need to replace my `notifyService`, with the event dispatcher of Symphony.

Here is the original service:

```
<?php

class VmService
{
    /**
     * @var VmManager|null
     */
    protected $vmManager = null;

    /**
     * @var ProvisionerInterface[]
     */
    protected $provisionners = array();

    /**
     * @var NotifyService|null
     */
    protected $notifyService = null;

    public function setVmManager(VmManager $vmManager)
    {
        $this->vmManager = $vmManager;
    }

    public function getVmManager()
    {
        return $this->vmManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param $type
     * @param ProvisionerInterface $provisionner
     */
    public function setProvisionner($type, ProvisionerInterface $provisionner)
    {
        $this->provisionners[$type] = $provisionner;
    }

    /**
     * @param $type
     * @return ProvisionerInterface
     */
    public function getProvisionner(Vm $vm)
    {
        return $this->provisionners[$vm->getType()];
    }

    /**
     * @param NotifyService $notifyService
     */
    public function setNotifyService(NotifyService $notifyService)
    {
        $this->notifyService = $notifyService;
    }

    /**
     * @return NotifyService|null
     */
    public function getNotifyService()
    {
        return $this->notifyService;
    }

    public function initialise(Vm $vm)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $provisioner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $provisioner->initialise($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(VM::STOPPED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
    }

    public function delete(Vm $vm, $force = false)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $day = $now->format('w');
        if ( ($day == 0 || $day == 6) && ! $force) {
            throw new \Exception('Cannot delete a VM on weekend unless you force it');
        }

        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $provisioner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $provisioner->delete($vm);

        $vm->setStatus(Vm::STOPPED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
    }

    private function deleteLogFile(Vm $vm)
    {
        $filename = VmLogger::getLogFile($vm->getIdVm());
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            @unlink("$filename");
        }
    }

    public function prepare(Vm $vm)
    {
        /**
         * @var VM $vm
         */
        $provisionner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);

        //$provisionner->start($vm, true, 'integ.lafourchette.local');
        $provisionner->stop($vm);
    }

    public function start(Vm $vm, $provisionEnable = true)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $notify = $this->getNotifyService();

        /**
         * @var VM $vm
         */
        $provisionner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);

        $vm->setStatus(VM::STARTED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
        try {
            $provisionner->start($vm, $provisionEnable);

            $vm->setStatus(VM::RUNNING);
            $vmManager->flush($vm);
            $notify->send('ready', $vm);

        } catch (UnableToStartException $e) {
            $vm->setStatus(VM::STOPPED);
            $vmManager->flush($vm);
            $notify->send('unable_to_start', $vm);
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function getStatus(Vm $vm)
    {
        return $this->getProvisionner($vm)->getStatus($vm);
    }

    public function stop(Vm $vm)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();

        /**
         * @var VM $vm
         */
        $provisionner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(Vm::STOPPED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
        $provisionner->stop($vm);
    }

    public function archived(Vm $vm)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $this->delete($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(VM::EXPIRED);
        $this->deleteLogFile($vm);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
        $this->prepare($vm);
    }
}
```

And here is what I've changed:

```
<?php

class VmService
{
    /**
     * @var VmManager|null
     */
    protected $vmManager = null;

    /**
     * @var ProvisionerInterface[]
     */
    protected $provisionners = array();

    /**
     * @var NotifyService|null
     */
    protected $notifyService = null;

    public function setVmManager(VmManager $vmManager)
    {
        $this->vmManager = $vmManager;
    }

    public function getVmManager()
    {
        return $this->vmManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param $type
     * @param ProvisionerInterface $provisionner
     */
    public function setProvisionner($type, ProvisionerInterface $provisionner)
    {
        $this->provisionners[$type] = $provisionner;
    }

    /**
     * @param $type
     * @return ProvisionerInterface
     */
    public function getProvisionner(Vm $vm)
    {
        return $this->provisionners[$vm->getType()];
    }

    /**
     * @param NotifyService $notifyService
     */
    public function setNotifyService(NotifyService $notifyService)
    {
        $this->notifyService = $notifyService;
    }

    /**
     * @return NotifyService|null
     */
    public function getNotifyService()
    {
        return $this->notifyService;
    }

    public function initialise(Vm $vm)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $provisioner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $provisioner->initialise($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(VM::STOPPED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
    }

    public function delete(Vm $vm, $force = false)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $day = $now->format('w');
        if ( ($day == 0 || $day == 6) && ! $force) {
            throw new \Exception('Cannot delete a VM on weekend unless you force it');
        }

        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $provisioner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $provisioner->delete($vm);

        $vm->setStatus(Vm::STOPPED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
    }

    private function deleteLogFile(Vm $vm)
    {
        $filename = VmLogger::getLogFile($vm->getIdVm());
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            @unlink("$filename");
        }
    }

    public function prepare(Vm $vm)
    {
        /**
         * @var VM $vm
         */
        $provisionner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);

        //$provisionner->start($vm, true, 'integ.lafourchette.local');
        $provisionner->stop($vm);
    }

    public function start(Vm $vm, $provisionEnable = true)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        /**
         * @var VM $vm
         */
        $provisionner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(VM::STARTED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
        try {
            $provisionner->start($vm, $provisionEnable);

            $vm->setStatus(VM::RUNNING);
            $vmManager->flush($vm);
            $event = new NotifyEvent($vm);
            $dispatcher->addListener('notify.action', $event);
            $dispatcher->dispatch('notify.action');


        } catch (UnableToStartException $e) {
            $vm->setStatus(VM::STOPPED);
            $vmManager->flush($vm);
            $event = new NotifyEvent($vm);
            $dispatcher->addListener('notify.action', $event);
            $dispatcher->dispatch('notify.action');

            throw $e;
        }
    }

    public function getStatus(Vm $vm)
    {
        return $this->getProvisionner($vm)->getStatus($vm);
    }

    public function stop(Vm $vm)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();

        /**
         * @var VM $vm
         */
        $provisionner = $this->getProvisionner($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(Vm::STOPPED);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
        $provisionner->stop($vm);
    }

    public function archived(Vm $vm)
    {
        $vmManager = $this->getVmManager();
        $this->delete($vm);
        $vm->setStatus(VM::EXPIRED);
        $this->deleteLogFile($vm);
        $vmManager->flush($vm);
        $this->prepare($vm);
    }
}
```

However as I see with the documentation, I need a listener but I can't figure out how to relate it, and how to make it to work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to refactor your code. [As stated in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html), in order to dispatch an event, you have to create the event and call the `dispatch` method on the *EventDispatcher* instance, so in your code instead of what you are doing currently:

```
<?php

// this is the start method of your service
// ...
$event = new NotifyEvent($vm);
$dispatcher->addListener('notify.action', $event);
$dispatcher->dispatch('notify.action');
// ...
```

you have to create the event and dispatch it directly:

```
<?php

// this is the start method of your service
// ...
$event = new NotifyEvent($vm);
$dispatcher->dispatch('notify.action', $event);
// ...
```

You also are sending the same event ('notify.action') now but previously you had 2 different events: 'ready' and 'unable_to_start', so you have to create 2 listeners for 2 differents events ('notify.success' and 'notify.unable_to_start' for example).

Now you have 2 more problems:

- No listeners are configured for your *'notify.action'* event, so you have to add listeners somewhere (you've tried but you've failed, see the documentation for the EventDispatcher component for more details about how to properly configure a listener)
- You're creating the dispatcher every time the `start` method is created, so you have to configure it every time also (configure means add the listeners)

You can tackle both if you refactor a little bit by creating another service based on the Symfony EventDispatcher:

```
<?php
// somewhere in your config file
// ...

$app['notifyService'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
   $dispatcher = new Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher();
   $dispatcher->addListener('notify.success', $callable1);
   $dispatcher->addListener('notify.unable_to_start', $callable2);

   return $dispatcher;
});
```

Notice that `$callable1` and `$callable2` are there to give you an idea, again check the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#connecting-listeners) to see how to add listeners properly (you can create a clousure or a method in a class that handles the events, it's completely up to you).

Now you've defined a notifyService based on the Event Dispatcher (another one completely different from the EventDispatcher used by Silex so you have a clean Event Dispatcher for your domain events), you can use it as a notify service on your class. You'd do it like before: using the `setNotifyService` method and in your code you just need to create the event and call the dispatch method (assuming you've already called the setNotifyService):

```
<?php
// class VmService
// method start
// when you've to dispatch the success event
$event = new NotifySuccessEvent($vm);
$this->notifyService->dispatch('notify.success', $event);

// if you have to dispatch the notify.unable_to_start event
$event = new NotifyUnableToStartEvent($vm);
$this->notifyService->dispatch('notify.unable_to_start', $event);
```

I hope that this will put you on the right track.

PS: You'll have to code the 2 event classes by yourself, again, check the docs for details.